# Neo4j: result of Cypher example query puzzles me

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying out the Cypher examples on the Neo4j website and one of the queries has me a bit puzzled.

There are three movie nodes with respective `title`s "The Matrix", "The Matrix Reloaded" and "The Matrix Revolutions". The Matrix node has `id` "603".

There are also three actor nodes with respective `name`s "Keanu Reeves", "Laurence Fishburne" and "Carrie-Anne Moss".

There are `ACTS_IN` relations between all actors and all movies.

This is a query that's supposed to return all the *other* movies that the actors in The Matrix acted in:

```
START matrix=node:node_auto_index(id="603") 
MATCH (matrix)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(movie) 
RETURN actor.name + ' acts in ' + movie.title;
```

And this is its (correct) result:

```
Keanu Reeves acts in The Matrix Reloaded
Keanu Reeves acts in The Matrix Revolutions
Laurence Fishburne acts in The Matrix Reloaded
Laurence Fishburne acts in The Matrix Revolutions
Carrie-Anne Moss acts in The Matrix Reloaded
Carrie-Anne Moss acts in The Matrix Revolutions
```

Why is The Matrix node *itself* not included in the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MATCH` clause specifies a path. A path might have loop, but will never contain the same relationship twice. In

```
MATCH (matrix)<-[:ACTS_IN]-(actor)-[:ACTS_IN]->(movie)
```

the two ACTS_IN relationships are always different. Therefore matrix is always not equal to movie since none of the actors has two ACTS_IN relationships to the same movie.

If you add multiple relationships form one actor to the same movie you'll get back matches having movie="The Matrix". A reason for this might be if an actor plays multiple characters.

### Update regarding 1st comment below:

In this case the query in natural languages would be: which movies have all the actors of the matrix acted in?

```
START matrix=node:node_auto_index(id="603") 
MATCH matrix<-[:ACTED_IN]-actor
WITH actor
MATCH actor-[:ACTED_IN]->movie
RETURN distinct movie.title;
```

The query is build up of two parts chained with the `WITH` statement:

1. find actors of the matrix
2. find all movies for those actors

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sense. But what would the query look like if I *did* want The Matrix included in the results? Without adding additional relationships, I mean.

Comment: see `Update` in answer above